How to control the size of an ActiveStorage embed in Prawn?
I use Prawn to export ActionText (Trim) to PDF.  This is straight forward.  However, ActionText embeds (images) are posing a challenge.  Because ActionText includes html, I am using prawn-markup to digest the html into the Prawn PDF.  prawn-markup understands images and discussing handling images in the README, but it's quite vague and ultimately not helpful.
If I do nothing, the embed image is rendered correctly inside the PDF, except it's huge---bigger than the source image.  If I generate the PDF using the following code:
markup(
  @communication.content.to_s,
  text: { size: 8 },
  image: {
    placeholder: 'img error',
    loader: -> (src) { nil }
  }
)

...the image loads correctly because the loader fails and therefor defaults back to the default https loader (in prawn-markup).  However, if I run this code:
markup(
  @communication.content.to_s,
  text: { size: 8 },
  image: {
    placeholder: 'img error',
    loader: -> (src) {
      if blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(src.split('/')[7])
        StringIO.new( blob&.download )
      end
    }
  }
)

..it also just returns the default https source image because the loader again fails.  It fails because ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(src.split('/')[7]) doesn't return a blob.  It returns nil.  Which is odd, because we know the image will load, then we grabbed the signed_id from that very same image, but when I use that signed_id to find the Blob, it is not found.  The error is due to a digest error.  I believe the Blob exists, but find_signed is failing because purpose: or some other attribute is not matching.
Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is something like this:
markup(
  @communication.content.to_s,
  text: { size: 8 },
  image: {
    placeholder: 'img error',
    loader: -> (src) {
      if blob = ActiveStorage::Blob.find_signed(src.split('/')[7])
        blob.variable? ? StringIO.new( blob.variant(resize: '50x50').processed.download ) : StringIO.new( blob&.download )
      end
    }
  }
)

..this would allow me to control the size of the image. Or, perhaps that's the wrong approach.  Perhaps I just need something like this:
markup(
  @communication.content.to_s,
  text: { size: 8 },
  image: {
    placeholder: 'img error',
    style: 'width: 100px' # or maybe this should be "width: '100px'"
  }
)

I just need control of the embedded image size.  Nothing above has worked for me.  How can I accomplish this?
